# I am trying to create an windows application using c# look like Dotnet IDE

Tags: windows

I am trying to create an windows application using c# look like Dotnet IDE. when i googling i have found some solution but that is not exact what i want. Anyone have any idea or have any refernce please share it with me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear, but if you're looking for some kind of a .NET UI library with the same controls as Visual Studio (is that what you mean by "Dotnet IDE"?) you're unlikely to find one. This is because Visual Studio itself is not written in .NET - it's written in unmanaged C++.

Of course, it's possible to create controls that look and work the same way, but I'm not aware of any libraries like that.

Comment: no not exactly like Dotnet IDE but look a like. like i need to give flexibility to user to create a form in my application like we create in dotnet. there is one toolbox like, there is property window..etc application should have drag and drop functionality etc..i hope it is claer

Comment: @dotnetcoder: Oh you way over your head. I don't think that that's going to happen.